# Can the Dell Repository Manager be used to deploy updates remotely?

Tags: dell

We have Dell DRM (not to be confused with digital rights management) installed in a VM that our production servers can reach. We have used DRM to download a catalog and the required update binaries ( firmware, BIOS etc.) for our hardware. 
Can we use DRM to push updates onto servers running CentOS Linux or do we need to use Dell dsu to pull them from our DRM local repo?

Thanks.